# view @{title()} how to disable appending config.name to the title?

Tags: total.js

I see framework is adding '-' + config.name to the passing title from view. How to disable it?
Example:

```
@{title('@(Categories list)'}
```

renders to:

```
<title>Categories list - [config.name variable]</title>
```

I want it to render to

```
<title>Categories list</title>
```

Comment: Use this config https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~FrameworkConfiguration~allow-custom-titles

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it via `allow-custom-titles : false` in `config`:
https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~FrameworkConfiguration~allow-custom-titles

Comment: No problem. BTW: my grandfather's name is Rosenberg :-)